# Add a method to all subclasses without changing the parent class

Tags: typescript, oop

I have an abstract class A, B and C both inherit A

Now I want to extend both B and C with the same methods, so basically I'd like B and C to inherit a class ExtendedA, but I don't want to change A, B and C

It could work with mixins however since A is abstract, the mixin function has no way to know that the abstract methods are actually implemented in B and C, so naturally it gives me an error:

```js
abstract class A {
    protected a = 1;

    public abstract hello(): void;
}

class B extends A {
    public hello() {
        console.log('hello from B');
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public hello() {
        console.log('hello from C');
    }
}

type AConstructor = new(...args: any[]) => A;

function ExtendedA<T extends AConstructor>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base {
        public doSomething() {
            this.hello();
            console.log('do something', this.a);
        }
    }
}


class ExtendedB extends ExtendedA(B) {
}

class ExtendedC extends ExtendedA(C) {
}

const d = new D();
const e = new E();

d.doSomething();
// hello from B
// do something 1
e.doSomething();
// hello from C
// do something 1
```

`test.ts:22:12 - error TS2653: Non-abstract class expression does not implement inherited abstract member 'hello' from class 'A'.`

am I not seeing something or is there no way to do it in typescript?

Comment: define new class D that inherits B and B inherits A : D->B->A and define new methods in D

Comment: no, i want B and C subclasses to get these new methods, im not going to copy paste the methods in D->B->A and E->C->A etc (knowing that there are more A subclasses than B and C in my case)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `AConstructor` defines a type that extends `A`, and `ExtendedA` is extending that type, but no class is implementing `A` (which is abstract) methods. Try using an interface instead:

```js
interface AInterface {
    hello();
}

type AConstructor = new (...args: any[]) => AInterface;

let ExtendedA = (Base: AConstructor): any => {
  return class extends Base {
    public doSomething() {
      this.hello();
      console.log("do something", this.a);
    }
  };
};
```

**Note**: protected property is not accesible from grandchildren, only for children.